# Is my work about vectors correct?

Tags: vectors

I have a question that involves vectors here:

$ O $ is the origin and the position vectors of three points $ P $, $ Q $ and $ R $ are $ \vec{p}, \vec{q} $ and $ 5\vec{p} $ respectively. $ M $ is a point on line $ \vec{PQ} $ such that $ \frac{\vec{PM}}{\vec{PQ}} = \frac{1}{4} $.

[My diagram showing the points based on the question, some points are added because they are included in the sub questions.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2Boh.jpg)

My information:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\vec{OP} &= \vec{p} \\
\vec{OQ} &= \vec{q} \\
\vec{OR} &= 5\cdot\vec{p} \\
\vec{OR} &= 5\cdot\vec{OP} 
\end{aligned}$$

a) Express $ \vec{OM} $ in terms of $ \vec{p} $ and $ \vec{q} $.

This one is pretty easy.
$ \vec{OM} = \vec{OP} + \vec{PM} $

But before I start solving, I first find the vector $ \vec{PM} $.
From the question, I can see that
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
&4 \cdot \vec{PM} \!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!&=& \; \vec{PQ} \\
\Leftrightarrow &\vec{PM} &=& \; \frac{1}{4} \cdot \vec{PQ} 
\end{aligned}$$

To find $ \vec{PQ} $:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\vec{PQ} &= \vec{PO} + \vec{OQ} \\
&= -\vec{OP} + \vec{OQ} \\
&= -\vec{p} + \vec{q}
\end{aligned}
$$

From here,

$$ \vec{PM} = -\frac{1}{4}\vec{p} + \frac{1}{4}\vec{q} $$

With these information:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\vec{OM} &= \vec{OP} + \vec{PM} \\
&= \vec{p} -\frac{1}{4}\vec{p} + \frac{1}{4}\vec{q} \\
&= \frac{3}{4}\vec{p} + \frac{1}{4}\vec{q}, \text{final answer}
\end{aligned}
$$

b) $ K $ is a point such that $ \vec{OK} = h \cdot \vec{OM} $, where $ h \gt 1 $. Express $ \vec{OK} $ and $ \vec{QK} $ in terms of $ \vec{p}, \vec{q} $ and $ \vec{h} $.

I am going to solve for $ \vec{OK} $ first. From the question, it says that vector $ \vec{OK} $ is vector $ \vec{OM} $ multiplied by a constant, $ h $. And since the question asks me to express $ \vec{OK} $ in terms of $ \vec{p}, \vec{q} $ and $ h $, I don’t need to find the actual value of $ h $. So my answer would be:

$$ \vec{OK} = \left(\frac{3}{4} \cdot h\right)\vec{p} + \left(\frac{1}{4} \cdot h\right)\vec{q} $$

Now onto solving $ \vec{QK} $.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\vec{QK} &= \vec{QO} + \vec{OK} \\
&= -\vec{OQ} + \vec{OK} \\
&= \frac{3h}{4}\vec{p} + \left(-\frac{3h}{4}\right)\vec{q}
\end{aligned}
$$

c) If $ \vec{QK} = \lambda x \cdot \vec{QR} $, find the value of $ \lambda $ and then constant $ h $.

This is where I got stuck. My working starts with finding $ \vec{QR} $.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\vec{QR} &= \vec{QO} + \vec{OR} \\
&= -\vec{OQ} + \vec{OR} \\
&= -\vec{q} + 5\vec{p} \\
&= 5\vec{p} - \vec{q}
\end{aligned}
$$

Then I equate them.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\text{Let} \; \lambda &= y\\
\vec{QK} &= y \cdot \vec{QR} \\
\frac{3h}{4}\vec{p} + \left(-\frac{3h}{4}\right)\vec{q} &= y \cdot \left(5\vec{p} - \vec{q}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Then I compare the like terms. I start with comparing the terms with $ \vec{p} $.
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{3h}{4}\vec{p} &= \left(5 \cdot y\right)\vec{p} \\
\frac{3h}{4} &= 5\cdot y \\
\frac{3h}{20} &= y
\end{aligned}
$$

Then terms with $ \vec{q} $.
$$
\begin{aligned}
-\frac{3h}{4} &= -y \\
-\frac{3h}{4} &= -\frac{3h}{20} \\
60h &= 12h \;\text{[THIS IS MY PROBLEM]}
\end{aligned}
$$
I don’t understand which part of my working is wrong, I’ve made sure that all of my working steps are correct. I hope someone could come and lend a helping hand to help me find my mistakes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found my mistake!

It’s located at the subquestion b). I made a mistake about finding vector $ \vec{QK} $.
$$
-\vec{q} + \left(\frac{3h}{4}\vec{p} + \frac{h}{4}\vec{q}\right)
$$

This is where I calculated wrong. I subtract $ 1 $ from $ -\frac{3h}{4} $ which is impossible because $ -1 $ doesn’t have constant $ h $. Hence, the correct vector for $ \vec{QK} $ is:
$$
\frac{3h}{4}\vec{p} + \left(\frac{h}{4} - 1\right)\vec{q}
$$

With this, let’s try solving c) again:
From comparing the like terms of $ \vec{p} $:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{3h}{4} &= 5y \\
    h &= \frac{20}{3}y
\end{aligned}
$$

Now comparing the like terms of $ \vec{q} $:
$$    \frac{h}{4} - 1 = -y $$
Sub $ h $ into this equation.
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{5y}{3} -1 &= -y \\
    \frac{8y}{3} &= 1 \\
    \frac{y}{\lambda} &= \frac{3}{8} \\
    h &= \frac{5}{2}
\end{aligned}
$$

Voila.